# Need to reload the page for my Jquery script to work again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons: menu_icon and exit_icon. When I click on the menu_icon, the menu shows (I just do an animation with CSS3). It goes away when I click exit_icon, but it will only work once. I have to reload the page if I want to re-open the menu.

Here is my JS code:

```
$(function(){

    $('#menu_icon').click(function() {
        $('nav').addClass('in');
    });

    $('#exit_icon').click(function() {
        $('nav').addClass('out');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the previous classes:

```
$('#menu_icon').click(function() {
    $('nav').removeClass('out').addClass('in');
});
$('#exit_icon').click(function() {
   $('nav').removeClass('in').addClass('out');
});
```